# Page hangs after too many DOM creation

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I currently make some async ajax calls and creates rows in table based on returning data. If rows are around 400-500, page hangs after this dom creations. eg. if i click any text box or drop-downs, it stuck forever. If rows are around 100-200 and then i click any text box, it is still slow but at least it does not stuck.

So, I think the problem is there are too many dom to be created and this causes some problems in browser or page or whatever.

Do you have any ideas or any solutions to improve this performance?

Answer (score 1):

You need to [lazy load](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading) your data somehow. Ever noticed on sites like Twitter, Facebook, and others that when you scroll to the bottom of the page it will begin loading more records from the server? Good apps will start to garbage collect old records that have been scrolled up as well.

When you scroll through your Facebook news feed it's not loading all your friends post since 2007 into the browser all at the same time. Once a maximum number of posts exists in the DOM Facebook will start removing the oldest ones you scrolled up to make room for more and grab fresh posts from the server so you can continue scrolling. You can even see your browser scroll bar jump up as you scroll down because more posts are being added to the DOM.

No browser is going to be able to handle that much data. You're going to have to sit down and think of a better way to show that data to the user.  Only you will know what experience your users will actually want, but no matter what you'll definitely have to reduce the amount of elements you're including on the page.

Example:

[image]

Notice how the browser scroll bar jumps up a bit when it gets to the bottom. Twitter gets to the bottom and then loads more data to scroll through. It will eventually start cleaning up data at the top of the page as well if I scroll far enough.

The simplest solution is probably going to be for you to pass up a page number with your ajax requests and have your server only return the results for that page of data.

Comment: Thanks for this good answer. I need to show all data at the same time because user edits the data at the same time and submit. So, scrolling or paging etc. options are not helpful in my case. It seems i need to limit row size(data size). eg. max 100.

Comment: Well if the problem is that you have too many DOM elements then you don't have a choice. You'll have to provide a way for them to edit data, then go to the next page and continue editing data. One way or another you'll need to shrink the DOM to keep your site usable.

Comment: Thank you! At least, I know now that there is nothing i can do with my current code. I need to figure out how to manipulate the DOM to make it less enough for page.